# How can I add a specific time zone to this code?

Tags: javascript

I have this code but the only thing is I can't figure out how to add a time zone to it. I have the date set but no time zone. How would I add it to the countDownDate?

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("May 8, 2018 16:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "<p>" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "</p>";

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "expired";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Your timezone, the server's timezone, the user's timezone?

Answer (score 0):

New Date() objects are in the system's local timezone. If you want to set a timezone directly, one way to do so would be to create your time in UTC time and then add the offset of the local timezone you are looking for.

```
let dateUTC = new Date(Date.UTC('...'))
let offset = (60*60*1000) * 4 // EST would be UTC+4, hence 4 * the number of ms in an hour.
let dateEST = dateUTC+offset
```

An alternative would be to just use a date string, with the timezone specified:

```
let dateEST = new Date('2018-05-08T14:45:00+0400') //The '+0400' is the '+4' for EST.
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just tried adding "GMT" to my date variable and it works. Didn't think that would.

So I now have:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("May 8, 2018 16:00:00 GMT").getTime();
```

And I set the time +/- from my time zone and it works.